# angularjs: how can I get the current page/component in spa app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have a sidebar in spa with functions and I need to get the current page that the function called from.
any solution with angularjs? maybe routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the angular [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) service for this purpose.

`$location.path()`, `$location.absUrl()` or `$location.url()` will satisfy you requirement.

Comment: thanks for your answer! maybe you know if I can get it with routing?